# Delete files in a directory using glob()

Tags: php

I am trying to empty the content of a directory using glob() and foreach() using

```
$files = glob('/upload/'.$id.'/temp/*.JPEG'); 
    foreach($file as $files){
    unlink($file);}
```

But I just keep getting 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'

Is this just a syntax error or can I not use unlink() in a foreach loop?

Also, just out of curiosity, will this code find all files in a directory?

```
$files = glob('/upload/'.$id.'/temp/*.*');
```

Comment: `foreach $files as $file` -- the ending `s` is in the wrong place.

Comment: Compressed form :) `array_map('unlink', glob('/upload/'.$id.'/temp/*.JPEG'));`. "Also, just out of curiosity, will this code find all files in a directory?": No, it will not find files _without_ a dot `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` means the argument you passed is not an array. Here you passed `$file`. `$file` is not array. In fact it does not exists yet.

The format of foreach is,

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
    statement
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

From your code the correct solution would be

```
foreach ($files as $file)
```